# Search string for strings contained in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an input field and I want to do a validation check that will prevent users from subitting SQL injection-like strings. How would this be done in JavaScript?

```
var userInput = '"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + txtUserId;'
var arrayCheck = [SELECT, FROM, WHERE];
```

So now I need to check userInput for the number of matches in the array arrayCheck.

If the number of matches is three or higher, return `false`, otherwise return `true`.

Comment: This is not a proper way! Will disturb UX.. Something like `mysqli_real_escape_string` will help! What if user want to input as `"WHERE is the mall? I want to SELECT 10 shirts FROM there"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for Strings in Strings using

```
var stringVar = 'test';
var x = stringVar.indexOf('test') > -1;
```

Basically, indexOf will return the index of the starting position of a string in a string, if it cant find it will return -1.

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

So for your problem you could so something like so.

```
function testForSQLKeyWords(inputText) {
  var keywords = ['SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE'];
  var threshold = 3;
  var hits = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    var keyword = keywords[i];
    if (inputText.indexOf(keyword) > -1) {
      hits++;
    }
  }
  return hits >= threshold;
}

//Then call it

var inputText = 'SELECT name FROM people';

testForSQLKeyWords(inputText);
```

May I also suggest thinking about maybe using `.toLowerCase` [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp).

Comment: What about for multiple string occurences?

Comment: improved my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could filter all your *arrayCheck* words and then count them, checking against the string:

```
var matches = arrayCheck.filter(function(item){
   return userInput.indexOf(item) > -1;
});
var numberOfMatches = matches.length;
if(numberOfMatches >= 3)
    //do your thing
```

Be careful, you could not match the words because of cases, i would recommend to lowercase or uppercase the entire string. Inside the filter:

```
return userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(item.toLowerCase());
```